# How to find the points which are part of the same diagonal in an orthonormal coordinate system

Tags: javascript, math

I have an array of objects that represents an orthonormal coordinate system where each object represent a point with a letter and the coordinates (x & y).

```
const array = [
  { x: 0, y: 0, value: 'A' },
  { x: 1, y: 0, value: 'B' },
  { x: 2, y: 0, value: 'C' },
  { x: 3, y: 0, value: 'D' },
  { x: 0, y: 1, value: 'E' },
  { x: 1, y: 1, value: 'F' },
  { x: 2, y: 1, value: 'G' },
  { x: 3, y: 1, value: 'H' },
  { x: 0, y: 2, value: 'I' },
  { x: 1, y: 2, value: 'J' },
  { x: 2, y: 2, value: 'K' },
  { x: 3, y: 2, value: 'L' },
  { x: 0, y: 3, value: 'M' },
  { x: 1, y: 3, value: 'N' },
  { x: 2, y: 3, value: 'O' },
  { x: 3, y: 3, value: 'P' },
]
```

There is a schematic representation:
[image: schematic representation of the array]

I need to find the points which are part of the same diagonal.
Example, take the point G.
I should find objects with values: B, L, D, J & M.

I cannot resolve this problem because of maths, I have no idea how I should proceed. What is the easier/smartest  way ?

NB: My coords are reversed, y go to the bottom instead the top (point M.y should be -3 instead 3 in normal way), does it matter ?

Comment: Hint: There are 2 diagonals. One diagonal has the common value of `x+y` and the other diagonal has the common value of `x-y`.

Comment: Are the diagonals exclusively those of the square? i.e are they always going to be multiples of (1,1) and (1,-1)?

Comment: @Makogan x = 0, x < 1000, y = 0, y < 1000 and there is a point for each coords

Comment: That's not what I am asking. What I am asking is what the directions of the diagonals are going to be. From a math stand point there are infinitely many diagonals, I want to know if you care only about the 2 such that x=y and x=-y

Comment: @Makogan yes only theses 2 diagonals

Answer (score 0):

I've found this pattern, maybe it helps:

For your example G:

```
    array[6] //G
    array[6+3] // J
    array[6+2*3] // M
    array[6-3] // D

    array[6-5] // B
    array[6+5] L
```

this pattern works for every letter as far as I can see, you only have to check for array out of bounds error

---

edit:
for every matrix size:

x is the size of the matrix,
then the two numbers you need are x + 1 and x - 1

so for size 4 you have 3 and 5

Comment: This is an example, it should works with a 1000 length array ^^

Comment: @TintinSansYeux I've added it into my answer

Answer (score 0):

Well as explained in my comment, your diagonals obey the rule that either x=y or x=-y.

So if x=y (e.g. (0,0); (1,1))... It's in one diagonal. If (x=-y) (e.g (1,-1), (10,-10)) then it's in the other. In all other cases, the point is not in a diagonal.

Your comments are a bit confusing, these are your points as described in the table.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. Example with G point =>  L point is in diagonal but neither x=-y / x=y

Comment: They are not in that diagonal. The direction from one point to the other is colinear with the diagonal, but the points themselves are not in it. So do you want the points to be in the diagonal, or do you want the directions between the points to be?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at a simple example, the A, F, K, P diagonal has `x == y`, so that's a starting point. Then we look at B, G, L and we notice that `x == y + 1`. And C, H has `x == y + 2`, so that's the start of a pattern in an of itself. So the algorithm might be `x == y + Alpha.x`, but that only works if you start at the first row. If we flip it around a bit, we get `x - y = t`, or `t = x - y` where `t` is equal for everything in that same diagonal. Now you can compare `t` with `A.x - A.y` and `B.x - B.y` to see they aren't in the same diagonal, but `E.x - E.y`  equals `J.x - J.y`, so they are in the same diagonal.

For the other diagonal, we can see that M, J ,G, D are in that same other direction diagonal. We can also see that `x + y = 4` for all of those cases. And I, F, C has `x + y = 2`, again for all of those cases, so now we can start to see that `u = x + y`, where `u` will be the same for everything in that diagonal as well.

So now we have 2 simple cases:

- t = x - y
- u = x + y

If `t` or `u` are equal to the `t` or `u` of another letter, it's in one of the same diagonals. Ex: `I.t == N.t` and `N.u == K.u`. This should work regardless the size or shape of your matrix, such as if it's a wide or tall rectangle. If it ends up with a hole in the middle, like a doughnut, it would be up to you to decide if you want to "jump" the hole or disregard anything on the other side of the hole. I showed you how it works with something other than a "corner to corner" situation, so that's built into the comparisons.

You don't even need to know the size of the matrix for this to work.

Also, this should work regardless of your coordinate system. The only thing that could change is which diagonal `t` and `u` represents.

Just remember that a comparison between `t` and `u` is meaningless.

PS - I don't normally use `t` or `u` as variables, but I thought I'd use letters not in the above matrix to try to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [{ x: 0, y: 0, value: 'A' }, { x: 1, y: 0, value: 'B' }, { x: 2, y: 0, value: 'C' }, { x: 3, y: 0, value: 'D' }, { x: 0, y: 1, value: 'E' }, { x: 1, y: 1, value: 'F' }, { x: 2, y: 1, value: 'G' }, { x: 3, y: 1, value: 'H' }, { x: 0, y: 2, value: 'I' }, { x: 1, y: 2, value: 'J' }, { x: 2, y: 2, value: 'K' }, { x: 3, y: 2, value: 'L' }, { x: 0, y: 3, value: 'M' }, { x: 1, y: 3, value: 'N' }, { x: 2, y: 3, value: 'O' }, { x: 3, y: 3, value: 'P' },]
// given a point P with coordinates (xp, yp) the equations of the two diagonal lines 
// passing from P are y1 = x - xp + yp and y2 = -x + xp + yp
// maxx, maxy are the max x and y values
const diagonalPoints = (xp, yp, maxx, maxy) => { 
    const ra = [];
    for (let x = 0; x <= maxx; x++) {
        const y1 = x - xp + yp;
        if (y1 >=0 && y1 <= maxy && !(x === xp && y1 === yp)) ra.push([x, y1]);
        const y2 = - x + xp + yp;
        if (y2 >=0 && y2 <= maxy && !(x === xp && y2 === yp)) ra.push([x, y2]);
    }
    return ra.flatMap(v => array.filter(point => point.x === v[0] && point.y === v[1]).map(z => z.value));
}
console.log(...diagonalPoints(2, 1, 3, 3));
```